# Issues with list not getting garbage collected after use in mvc

Tags: c#, memory-management, asp.net-core-mvc

Backstory: I'm generating csv files as reports, and is testing to see what happens if multiple big reports are generated, this below should generate around 4 MB csv file, so if I called to get this report 2 times my pc would throttle at my 16 GB of ram, even after getting the files the program still uses all my ram, only by restarting the program can I clear up my ram. The ram is mostly used on boilerplate of the SMS class.

My issue is that the tmp list is never cleared/cleaned up by the garbage collector, even after the controller call is finished, which ends in large amounts of ram getting used.

I can see that the ram usage is only increasing when generating the tmp list not when creating the csv file

The console output

[image]

Visual studio Memory diagnostic after clicking download once

[image]

Snapshot of memory

[image]

```
private static readonly Random random = new();
private string GenerateString(int length = 30)
{
    StringBuilder str_build = new StringBuilder();
    Random random = new Random();

    char letter;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        double flt = random.NextDouble();
        int shift = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(25 * flt));
        letter = Convert.ToChar(shift + 65);
        str_build.Append(letter);
    }
    return str_build.ToString();
}

[HttpGet("SMS")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetSMSExport([FromQuery]string phoneNumber)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Generating items: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished generating items: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Generating CSV: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    var tmp = new List<SMS>();
    // tmp never gets cleared by the garbage collector, even if its not used after the call is finished
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        tmp.Add(new SMS() { 
           GatewayName = GenerateString(),
           Message = GenerateString(),
           Status = GenerateString()
        });
    }
    // 1048574 is max, excel says 1048576 is max but because of header and seperater line it needs to be minussed with 2
    ActionResult csv = await ExportDataAsCSV(tmp, $"SMS_Report.csv");
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished generating CSV: {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}");
    return csv;
}
```

```
private async Task<ActionResult> ExportDataAsCSV(IEnumerable<object> listToExport, string fileName)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Creating file");
    if (listToExport is null || !listToExport.Any())
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(listToExport));

    System.IO.File.Delete("Reports/" + GenerateString() + fileName);
    var file = System.IO.File.Create("Reports/" + GenerateString() + fileName, 4096, FileOptions.DeleteOnClose);

    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);


    await streamWriter.WriteAsync("sep=;");
    await streamWriter.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);

    var headerNames = listToExport.First().GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var header in headerNames)
    {
        var displayAttribute = header.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute),true);
        if (displayAttribute.Length != 0)
        {
            var attribute = displayAttribute.Single() as System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.DisplayAttribute;
            await streamWriter.WriteAsync(sharedLocalizer[attribute.Name] + ";");
        }
        else
            await streamWriter.WriteAsync(header.Name + ";");
    }
    await streamWriter.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);

    var newListToExport = listToExport.ToArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < newListToExport.Length; j++)
    {
        object item = newListToExport[j];
        var itemProperties = item.GetType().GetProperties();
        for (int i = 0; i < itemProperties.Length; i++)
        {
            await streamWriter.WriteAsync(itemProperties[i].GetValue(item)?.ToString() + ";");
        }
        await streamWriter.WriteAsync(Environment.NewLine);
    }
    Helpers.LogHelper.Log(Helpers.LogHelper.LogType.Info, GetType(), $"User {User.Identity.Name} downloaded {fileName}");
    await file.FlushAsync();
    file.Position = 0;
    
    return File(file, "text/csv", fileName);
}
```

```
public class SMS
{
    

    [Display(Name = "Sent_at_text")]
    public DateTime? SentAtUtc { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "gateway_name")]
    public string GatewayName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "message_title")]
    [JsonProperty("messageText")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "status_title")]
    [JsonProperty("statusText")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Not going to go through all that code, but there's a bunch of objects that you should be `using`

Comment: Cant get using to work on the tmp list since the type of list is not a type of IDisposable

Comment: Adding using on the streamWriter makes the application throw
"System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be found in this post
[MVC memory issue, memory not getting cleared after controller call is finished (Example project included)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67634195/mvc-memory-issue-memory-not-getting-cleared-after-controller-call-is-finished/67787752#67787752)

Copied answer

The [github](https://github.com/jespper/Memory-Issue) version is a fixed version for this issue, so you can go explorer what i did in the changeset

Notes:

1. After generating a large file, you might need to download smaller sized files before C# releases the memory
2. Adding forced garbage collection helped alot
3. Adding a few using statements also helped alot

Smaller existing issues

1. If your object cant fit in the RAM and it start filling the pagefile it will not reduce the pagefile after use(Restarting your pc will help a little on it but wont clear the pagefile entirely)
2. I couldnt get it below 400MB of ram usage no matter what i tried, but it didnt matter if i had 5GB or 1GB in the RAM it would still get reduced down to ~400 MB