# MVC memory issue, memory not getting cleared after controller call is finished (Example project included)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, memory-management, asp.net-core-mvc

My issue: After calling a controller which generates csv file content and returns, memory is not cleared up. Which generates issue since it will slowly fill up memory and you'll end up using 100% memory on your server after awhile, this issue can be hastened by just generating larger csv files example in the project below it simply generates 3 million lines of csv file content which fills memory quite a bit.

What I want: Simply it clears the memory after the content is finished getting used.

I've tried a few thing with using statement and IDisposable but none of them fixed the issue.
Only way I can think of is using pointers and clearing the RAM manually since the garbage collector for some reason is not removing the old data which is not getting used anymore.

The RAM usage problem is mostly contained around the "test" function and GetDymmyData.

I have not added code examples in this post since I've tried to do that in [Issues with list not getting garbage collected after use in mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67297099/issues-with-list-not-getting-garbage-collected-after-use-in-mvc?noredirect=1#comment118951790_67297099)
but it ended up being too much code

Example project: https://github.com/jespper/Memory-Issue

Comment: Have you tried [using a `finalizer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/destructors) to do a last minute cleanup of the object?  Putting a break point in there and dispose will tell you if the memory leak is the lack of cleanup at the end, or diagnose a leak in the main blocks.

Comment: Things that stick out to me: 1) You create a random for every generated line, rather than using a shared `Random` instance for the whole exporter. 2) You're calling `GetType().GetProperties()` in a `foreach` twice - that might be causing lots of reflection-related stuff to be regenerated that doesn't need to be when you could just get them once (assuming each object is of a fixed small set of types).

Comment: @DekuDesu I've just tested out adding a finalizer to the export class funny enough the finalizer never gets called for some reason, not sure why i even tried to encapsulate the using statement around the await export.test() function

Comment: @MartinCostello if i comment out the ExportDataAsCsv function the memory issue doesnt get fixed, so dont think GetType().GetProperties() is the general issue here, i will thank for the Random reminder and moved that as a class variable

Comment: Lol,  had to really look. Funny you put your business logic in the Models directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The github version is a fixed version for this issue, so you can go explorer what i did in the changeset

Notes:

1. After generating a large file, you might need to download smaller sized files before C# releases the memory
2. Adding forced garbage collection helped alot
3. Adding a few using statements also helped alot

Smaller existing issues

1. If your object cant fit in the RAM and it start filling the pagefile it will not reduce the pagefile after use(Restarting your pc will help a little on it but wont clear the pagefile entirely)
2. I couldnt get it below 400MB of ram usage no matter what i tried, but it didnt matter if i had 5GB or 1GB in the RAM it would still get reduced down to ~400 MB

Comment: It seems you are calling supressfinalize on the object before calling the garbage collector. Furthermore, it doesn't seem like you're dying any cleanup yourself at all.